# End stored procedure with a select - 1 of 3 possible depending on a condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have conditions - 3 of them, mutually exclusive. I have no problem coding them and assigning a 'Y' to `@condition1`, 'Y' to `@condition2`, or finally, 'Y' to `@condition3`.  (again, mutually exclusive - only one will pan out).

And based on those, I want to either select one particular select, or select another particular select, or select a third possible select.

Like:

```
if @c1 = 'Y' 
begin
    select * from temptable1
end

if @c2 = 'Y'
begin
    select * temptable2
end

if @c3 = 'Y'
begin
    select * from temptable3
end
```

(sorry I wrestled with S.O. indenting until had a hard time indenting, ignore ugliness).

So things I have tried:

1. do exactly as I've coded above - what ends up happening is that NO records are returned
2. do what I coded above, except, basically `select * into temptable1` if this, `select * into temptable2` if that, `select * into temptable3` if that, and then `if condition1=true select * from temptable1`, `if condition2 = true select * from temptable2`, etc. etc.  the problem is that it refuses to compile because it thinks all temptables are being created each run, even tho they're not.

Comment: Is there any chance that _all_ of your mutually exclusive conditions are false?

Comment: For grins, since all of your options are mutually exclusive you can use if/else to check them. That ensures that you don't execute multiple `select`s and lets you tack `else select 'None of the above'` on the end where it will "never" be reached.

Comment: Aww - yep you were right.  I think I had the last condition slightly wrong and they were, in fact, all false.  Thank you - I just needed a 2nd set of eyes.  Thanks again.